# Lazy loading children component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I have a component, it's working fine until I didn't add an heavy children component that freeze the page. Now I would implement a lazy loading for the children component (is that the right solution?).

Also, I start to load the component only if "dataForMapReady" is true.

Actually, that's my html in fhater:

FATHER HTML

```
<div style="margin: 1.5em 1.5em;" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
  <div *ngIf="dataForMapReady">
    <mm-map-management [newsearch]="newsearch" [parameters]="parametersToMap" [resultsTotal]="results.total" [checkedFavorite]="checkedFavorite" [sortField]="sortField" [sortDir]="sortDir"></mm-map-management>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't understand how to implement lazy loading in this case, I'm newbie of Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your applicatuion must be devided in modules to Implement Lazy-loading

In your routing module, you need to set routing for child compmenents something like

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'items',
        loadChildren: () => import('./items/items.module').then(m => m.ItemsModule)
    }
];
```

You can download sample App for lazy Loading implementation
https://angular.io/generated/zips/lazy-loading-ngmodules/lazy-loading-ngmodules.zip

Configuring step-by-step lazy-loaded route
https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: You can also check live example on Stackblitz.
https://stackblitz.com/angular/vmkgeddbjer?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts

Comment: Actually my app-routing.module.ts is like this: const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "companies", component: AppCompanies}, can't use your tip above

Comment: It should be something like   { path: "companies", loadChildren: () => import('./companies/companies.component').then(m => m.AppCompanies).then(MmMapManagementComponent) no?

Comment: In step 1 there should be separate module for companies and component
In step 2 you need to load your companies component in companies module
In step 3 you need to load your companies module in your main routing file
For detailed working see https://stackblitz.com/angular/vmkgeddbjer?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts